# How to convert text file to conll 2012 format for co-reference resolution system

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on training co-reference resolution system(statistical coreference model) for a new domain . I need to convert my data to conll 2012 data format. Please help

I am using  following text format. I would like to know whether Stanford provides any functionalities to convert below data to conll 2012 format.
To comprehend Bunuel 's works it is essential to understand that he was first a Spaniard and secondly a product of Spanish bourgeoisie .
Virginia Higgenbotham points out that `blasphemy is only a form of thinking for any intelligent Spaniard , '' and also that the` art of his country is rich in eroticism and profoundly preoccupied with death '' -LRB- 18 , 20 -RRB- .
Bunuel says : My infancy slipped by in an almost medieval atmosphere -LRB- like that of nearly all the Spanish provinces -RRB- between my native town and Zaragova .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review [this Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The full spec for this data format is available [here](http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html) -- if you have a specific programming question related to implementing this spec you can ask it on this site.  Simply stating "I need to convert my data" won't get you useful answers here.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the data format. I would like to know whether Stanford provides any functionalities to convert below data to conll 2012 format.